# Python main() not executing properly

Tags: python

In my python program, I have multiple functions defined, then a main function that also holds the menu. The menu is the first thing that should be displayed, but the program is attempting to run the defined functions that are before the main function, first. This is resulting in many problems. Any suggestions.

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import operator

saved_string = ''


def remove_letter():                          
    return

def num_compare():                            
    return

def print_string():                          
    print saved_string
    return

def calculator():                             
    sign_dict = {"+": operator.add(), "-": operator.sub(), "*": operator.mul(), "&": operator.div()}

    num1 = int(raw_input("First number: "))
    sign = str(raw_input("Action: "))
    num2 = int(raw_input("Second number: "))


    print sign_dict[sign] (num1, num2)



    return

def accept_store():
    global saved_string                          
    saved_string = str(raw_input("Enter string: "))
    return

def main():                                    
    opt_list = [accept_store(),
                calculator(),
                print_string(),
                num_compare(),
                remove_letter()]

    while(True):
        print "SELLECT OPTIONS:"
        print "1\tAccept and Store"
        print "2\tCalculator"
        print "3\tPrint String"
        print "4\tNumber Compare"
        print "5\tRemove Letter"
        opt_choice = int(raw_input("SELLECTION: "))
        opt_choice -= 1
        opt_list[opt_choice]()


    return


main()
```

Comment: Change `[accept_store(),calculator(),...]` to `[accept_store,calculator,...]`

Comment: please correct your indentation so that people can hep you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` is a function call notation. So in `opt_list`, you're listing all the function *calls*, not the function names. You'd have to change it to:

```
opt_list = [fn1, fn2, ...]
```

Then call each function like:

```
for f in opt_list:
    f()
```

Comment: For loop not needed. `opt_list[opt_choice]()` is correct. The list just needs changed

Comment: @cricket_007 I just wanted to show him how to call a function inside the list.

Comment: I know. And I'm saying that part should already be handled by that code I commented with

Comment: Posh_Pumkin, that worked great! Now in the calculator funtion, the:

Comment: The print statement : print sign_dict[sign] (num1, num2) is causing problems

Comment: @cricket_007 I know what you mean. Like I said, I didn't want to tell him "if you delete the parentheses in the list, your code will magically start working."

Comment: @JacobQuam That's because your `print` statement has incorrect syntax. Do some googling and *then* post another question for it.